# Why are x509 certificates associated with IAM Users in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, x509certificate, amazon-iam

I'm reading the AWS docs and am a little confused as to why x.509 certificates are associated to specific IAM Users in AWS. I can't really find an answer so I feel I'm missing something.

Can anyone tell me why this is? I've done my Googling and read up on the documents but it seems that the logic behind why this is, is implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is legacy functionality, no longer serving any useful purpose.  Many years ago, X.509 certificates were used to sign requests for AWS SOAP APIs.

All of these are likely deprecated if not gone entirely.

In some cases -- like EC2 -- the SOAP functionality was deprecated and later [completely removed from the API and SDKs in late 2015](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/using-soap-api.html).

So this IAM feature would only be used for legacy systems using other AWS services that still support the old SOAP APIs that expect X.509-based authentication, assuming there are any.  If there are, the documentation has long since been deleted or is buried, as is the case for [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APISoap.html), which only supports SOAP over HTTPS these days, and appears to expect Access Keys rather than certificates.

Perhaps SimpleDB still supports the old SOAP API.  SimpleDB?  One of the original Amazon Web Services like SQS and S3, SimpleDB was -- sort of, kind of, in a manner of speaking, loosely -- a predecessor to DynamoDB... it was quite an innovation back in its day, and it is still alive though perhaps not well, and you will be hard-pressed to find anyone talk about it, or find much evidence of it in the AWS documentation, though it's there [if you know where to look](https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/).  SimpleDB hasn't been deployed in any AWS region that launched after about 2013.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought this question was going to be lost in the pile.